# How to create a filter with multiple values in google data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am using google data studio and I created a filter so that a field of mine reads only specific values. The filter is the one below:

[image]

I need to have multiple values for my filter and it seems there is no `IN` operator so I had to use `OR`. But it doesn't allow me to use the same field when I do so.

So how can I have a filter like:

`WHERE field_value IN (12345, 678910, ...)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's retricting you to not using "IN" because it's a metric but if you create a copy of the metric and change its type to "TEXT" you can then use "IN".